# Storing C struct array to core data or on disk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, struct, mkpolyline

I am working on an App that records location points and draws a path on MapView using an MKPolyline, which requires a C struct array of location points with latitude and longitude. Currently I save CLLocation objects in CoreData for each path, but when I want to display them I need to enumerate the CLLocations and create a C struct array with those CLLocation points. This is a problem since it takes longer if there're a lot of points to enumerate.

I'm looking for a solution to be able to **save large number of location points on disk and be able to load them very fast and add them to an MKPolyline**. I would really appreciate your help.

**EDIT:** My locations array is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` array.

Comment: Try using CoreData.  This is the best way to persist large amounts of data.  There are plenty of examples of how to use CoreData on the Internet.

Comment: You could write a value transformer. Not sure if it will yield the same performance. Can check it out.

Comment: @Rakesh: I tried the value transformer but apparently only objects that respond to the encodeWithCoder: can be saved.

Comment: @Rakesh: How can I use NSValue?

Comment: @ArminM: Check out the answer. A suggestion, you might want to consider changing the question title to something like 'storing c struct array to core data' or something of the like. More people might  take a look at the question, and odds of it getting answered will increase and it might help more people also. :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought NSValue could be used by using `value:withObjCType:`. But according to the documentation variable length types cannot be used.

> The type you specify must be of constant length. You cannot store C
>   strings, variable-length arrays and structures, and other data types
>   of indeterminate length in an NSValue—you should use NSString or
>   NSData objects for these types.

Assuming this:

```
//Sample data    
typedef struct {
    CGFloat lat;
    CGFloat longi;
}Location;

Location list[2];
Location get[2];

Location l1;
l1.lat = 10.0;
l1.longi = 4.0;

Location l2;
l2.lat = 3.0;
l2.longi = 4.0f;

list[0] = l1;
list[1] = l2;
```

You can use `NSData` the following way for your requirement:

```
//This is the part you want
//create NSData
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:list length:sizeof(list)];

//get c array from NSData
[data getBytes:&get length:sizeof(list)];

//accessing 
methodUsingCarray(getList);
NSLog(@"%f",get[0].lat); // only if you need to access individual points
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried storing in CoreData using transformable attributes but it doesn't work due to the same limitation you mentioned. I have no problem parsing my array and saving points separately, but I don't want to do that! When I have a large array with thousands of points, it takes time for it to be converted from the stored format to a C array and reverse. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: @ArminM: Here you are not parsing it. If you take a closer look, the C Array is stored as NSData , and **without parsing** or **enumerating** you are getting it back in `getList`. The first part I just made so that I have some sample data. But you need to effectively do only the last part.And if you want to pass the C array, pass `getList` .

Comment: Oh ok i see. It seems like it should work so I will accept your answer until I make it work. Is there any limitations to this method? Would I loose anything by saving C structs into Core Data?

Comment: Technically you are saving NSData to Core Data. Anyway it shouldn't be  a problem as far as I know and there are no rules being broken here. As you are dealing with quite some amount of data Core Data would be the right choice. Its a very robust framework.

Comment: Ok I used this and it gives a compiler error: "Sending `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to parameter of incompatible type `const void`* "
My array is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` array of location points.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) or another key-value data store library?  They tend to be very fast, very lightweight, and it looks like people have gotten some of them working on iOS. BerkeleyDB is owned by Oracle now, and it's free for open source apps.

Another popular key-value store is [Kyoto Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/), which is GPL'd.

Google has an MIT-licensed key-value store called [LevelDB](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb/), and it looks like there's even an [objective-C wrapper](https://github.com/hoisie/LevelDB-ObjC).

Comment: Thanks for the resources you have suggested. They look too complex to implement, and I'm looking for a simpler iOS way to solve this but apparently I can't. I might use the Berkeley DB later on if I can figure it out. It looks very promising.